# ASPNET MVC3: user is (almost) always redirected to login page: session problem or wrong config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have published an ASPNET MVC3 application to a service hosting. I use standard Account controller and I've seen that, during app execution - after a DB save - it loses account and the user is continuously redirected to the Login page.

This does not happen on my devel machine.

Do you know which problem is it?

### Edit

I've put today my ASPNET MVC3 app on WinHosting. The app uses native Forms Authentication used in MVC. I have an AdminController that can be accessed only by authenticated users. when the user goes to Admin/xyz the system correctly redirects him to the login page to authenticate him.

The problem is that when the user is authenticated and waits 10-15 seconds, when he clicks on a link, he is always redirected to the login form even if he is authenticated.

I thought it was a session problem and I asked WinHosting to use SQLServer sessions but I see that the SQL tables (AspStateTemp*) that should handle sessions data are always empty.

Here is the node I added in web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase = "true" 
sqlConnectionString="data Source=tcp:DB_server;database=DB_name;user id=DB_user;password=DB_passwd" 
cookieless="false" 
timeout="600" />
```

Comment: hard to diagnose without more information... architecture, component used, code of the save method, extract of the web.config....

Comment: Any chance the machineKeys aren't synchronized between the nodes of the web farm?

Comment: dont know; their "support" told me that they cannot debug my code. I really think it is a config problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem: http://forum.winhost.com/showthread.php?p=18258#post18258

Comment: don't forget to mark as answer so the question can be skipped by SO hawks :)